# Local images are fine in 4.4.2 but not being shown on WebView in Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, html, image, webview, android-webview

I have some images in my opening screen,  some are on the page, some are not when I install the apk into the phone. I tried to find a solution but none worked for me.
Any idea why the following scenario exists at all ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css" />

<script src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

The weird things;

- It works in my LG G2 (4.4.2)
- It DOES not work in Samsung  S2 (4.2.2) even though the images are in the same folder and they are all in .jpg format, the images in the first div work, the ones in the second div not working.

**The working piece in the same html;**

```
    <div data-role="header" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <center><img style="padding-bottom:10px;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/logo.png" />
        </center>
        <center><img style="max-width:100%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/header_image.jpg" />
        </center>
    </div>
```

**The piece that is not working at all ;**  (I do not see the images in the table inside the div, works in the browser, emulator, LG G2 with Android version 4.4.2 !)

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <table style="width:100%; margin-top:3%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="./19.html" data-transition="fade">
                            <center><img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/1.jpg" />
                            </center>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="./27.html" data-transition="fade">
                            <center><img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/2.jpg" />
                            </center>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:5%;">
                        <a href="./116.html" data-transition="fade">
                            <center><img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/3.jpg" />
                            </center>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-top:5%;">
                        <a href="./132.html" data-transition="fade">
                            <center><img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/4.jpg" />
                            </center>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**MainActivity;**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        // Enable Javascript
           WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
           webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
           //mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
           mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
           mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
           mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
           mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
           mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

           mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/18.html");
    }
```

Comment: `The piece that is not working at all ;`. You don't see a table? Please give it a border.

Comment: Sorry you're right.  I do not see the images inside the table (when I put a text inside the <td> tag, I am able to see it though ! ) .But as I said,  works just fine in LG G2.  How to overcome these differences ? It is really annoying.

Comment: Try also with logo.png and the other .png.

Comment: Nope that did not work in the table either !  I tried the opposite as well. Weirdly when I take the images out of the table, they just get showed !!!  So the problem is with the rendering of table in Android v. 4.2 - webView ?

Comment: Try with <table> and <td> without a style attribute.

Comment: Well when I remove the style attribute, the table disappears from the window just because it's size and width causes that happening, I believe. 
That may be a sign though.  I'm using jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js , and jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css .   Do you think it is regarding these versions ? 
Because when I click on the frame of the table in the design panel of Dreamweaver, it notifies me that jqueryMobile: main (UNRECOGNIZED ROLE VALUE) .

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Add border="2" to <table> and <td>

Comment: I tried that as well. Border , or border colors had no effect on the design. Somehow, the webview does not respond to that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am pretty surprised that "**center**" tag is the one causing to the problem.
    When I removed it from the surrounding of "**img**" tags, the problem disappeared for S2 with 4.2.2.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <table style="width:100%; margin-top:3%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="./19.html" data-transition="fade">
                                <img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/1.jpg" />

                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="./27.html" data-transition="fade">
                                <img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/2.jpg" />

                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:5%;">
                            <a href="./116.html" data-transition="fade">
                                <img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/3.jpg" />

                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-top:5%;">
                            <a href="./132.html" data-transition="fade">
                                <img style="max-height:58%; max-width:95%;" src="file:///android_asset/www/images/openingPage/4.jpg" />

                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```